Must a business property-owner erect a fence?
A new multi-story apartment building (first floor dedicated to shops) was just built next to our lot -- they are finishing up the interior work and are opening up the leasing office.
I'd like them to erect a fence -- to block the views, would-be trespassers, and any wind-blown trash from getting into my backyard.
Is there any actual law in NJ, that requires a fence in such a situation? Other buildings like this all have fences, but I don't know, whether that's required.
My own searches only return the regulations on what your fence must be like, if you want one -- but nothing on whether/when one is required...

"Other buildings like this all have fences" ... should yours have one, so that your trash doesn't blow onto their lot?

That would have been something to bring up when the project was undergoing planning permission, if there was any public review or you knew about the project.

And if they put up a fence that you think is ugly? Preemptively putting up your own fence might just be the best bet.

@WeatherVane, mine is a single family house and so far less trash to begin with. And far less likely, that we'll miss the garbage can -- than one of the 24 families there will.


Is there any actual law in NJ, that requires a fence in such a
situation?

There might be some isolated local ordinance or planned unit development plan somewhere that requires that, but generally no, not in this situation. A fence is not required. If you want a fence, you can build one (subject to local fencing regulations which are common and quite varied).

Other buildings like this all have fences, but I don't know, whether
that's required.

There are lots of good reasons to build a fence, but it isn't required in most cases (apart from jails and prisons and national security facilities), although there are good reasons in tort law (the law of liability for accidents) to fence outdoor swimming pools and drainage areas and it may be required in some instances in those circumstances.
